# How to run a jQuery Function in smaller width?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a something in a smaller width of screen But I have a problem. I'm creating a Responsive Navbar, So I want to show a Button when It is in small width & toggling the Menu. But when I hide the Menu in smaller width, It doesn't show the Menu in wider width Because of Hiding in jQuery ...

So I wanted to make jQuery Codes run JUST in smaller width, I wrote this But It doesn't work :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < '48em') {
        $('.ji-toggle-btn').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
        });                 
    }
});
```

Comment: use @media queries or bootstrap.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question ... ;)

Comment: Yes, I got your question. You code for the button instead of menu-items, so that you can see that in small screen. But then you realized that in bigger screen also, the button shows up. Instead you want to show menu-items in the big screen. Am I right??

Comment: No Vishal, My problem is not in CSS ..., Imaging I have created a Navbar ...
So I have put a button when screen for example is less than 400px to open & close a navbar ... But when I'm in that size I click button to hide the menu, It doesn't show the navbar in wider that 400px, Because It has been hidden in jQuery ..., So I want to run that jQuery code in JUST for example 400px to doesn't work in wider screens ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to show/hide a button is with a media query in CSS:

`.css` example:

```
.ji-toggle-btn {
  display: none;
}    

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .ji-toggle-btn {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

`.scss` example:

```
.ji-toggle-btn {
  display: none;

  @media (min-width: 48em) {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I mocked up a sample of how to do a responsive sidebar:
http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/dGOMYO

What you'll notice in this example is how little JS is used. Targeting a `.toggle` class and using css transitions will get you where you want to go. You're overthinking this approach with the JS.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question too ... ;)

Comment: Check the example I linked out to - I think it will get you where you need to go. You don't need much JS - think about toggling a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

$(window).width() returns an int (screen width in pixels). In order to get that value in ems you need to divide that buy the body's font-size, then compare that with just '48' not '48em'. For example:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(($(window).width() / parseFloat($("body").css("font-size"))) < 48) {
        //  Do stuff here...              
    }
});
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKaYNB is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Exactly in your Test is my problem ..., Make your screen smaller & click the button to hide the navbar, Then make screen wider, It doesn't show the navbar ..., This is what I want Pat ...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're assigning a behavior on smaller resolution. You practically want to assign a click event only when the window size is smaller than 48 em.

With simple words - just remove the click event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < '48em') {
        $('.ji-toggle-btn').parent().find('ul').toggle();
    }
});
```

**EDIT** I agree with the guy above about the CSS. Those things basically should be done with media queries.